# How to align Magento block of products vertically?

Tags: magento, php

After installing a mobile template on magento, new products block appear horizontally and the other vertically (see photo)

[image: New products Horizontal vs vertical]

What command do I have to use to make all of them vertically?

Comment: It seems that you are playing with a template component: check if in the xml related file you could set list instead grid and if this fix the game :)